# Implementing callback in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I want to implement some kind of callback in Qt.

I have a class called **ApiHandler** for making requests. And i should have a way to pass a function as callback to **makeRequest** and execute it when **replyFinished**.
I know a way using **std::function/std::bind**. But maybe there are ways to do this using Qt? Slots? Or more detailed explanation about using **std::function/std::bind** in this case.

Thanks!

```
typedef void (*callback)();
void ApiHandler::makeRequest(QString method, QMap<QString, QString> parameters, callback)
{
    QUrl url = this->buildCall(method, parameters);

    connect(this->manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*, callback)));

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Test");

    QNetworkReply *reply = this->manager->get(request);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)), this, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
}
void ApiHandler::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply, callback)
{
    qDebug() << "replyFinished" << reply->url();
    QJsonDocument j = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());
    if (j.isEmpty()) {
        // throw error
    }

    // call the callback with "j" as parameter
    // callback(j)

    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: What's the case of use? You need std::function, only if the callback can't be resolved at compile time. If you know all the callbacks baforehand then make them slots.

Comment: I can make a different calls, like this `QMap<QString, QString> m;
    m["user_id"] = this->settings.value(USER_ID).toString();

    ApiHandler *a = new ApiHandler;
    a->makeRequest("users.isAppUser", m, testCallback);`

And i should need to pass different callback. In example if i call this from app start i pass callback to display a warning, if i call this from about window i pass callback to display whatever user is using app.

Comment: You either use different objects, for different signals, or [disconnect and connect slots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524925/how-to-disconnect-a-signal-with-a-slot-temporarily-in-qt) on context

Comment: You basically need an agent to convert `reply` to `j`, so why not make such an agent class? Like when you `makeRequest` you `new` and agent, then connect the receiving side of the agent to the reply and sending side to the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using signals and slots and the `makeRequest` parameters are already Qt based types, you could just pass in a Request instance that derives from QObject and has a signal.

```
class Request : public QObject
{
public:
      QString method();
      QMap<QString, QString> parameters();

 signals:
     void received( QJsonDocument );
};
```

`replyFinished` could then be passed a `Request` instead of the callback

```
void ApiHandler::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply, Request* request )
```

and when eveything is ready you just fire the signal.

```
request->received( j );
```

Before passing in the `Request` you just connect whatever you want.

```
connect( request, &Request::received, [=]( QJSonDocument ) {
    // whatever ...
} );
```

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is not clear. In particular, the answer does not show how to use the callback function. In the phrase "replyFinished could then be passed a Request instead of a callback " the use of passive voice effectively prevents the reader from understanding where you create the Request object and where you pass this object to replyFinished. "and then when everything is ready"? What does than mean? "you just connect whatever you want"? Not very helpful. Sorry.

Comment: Thought I'd put it here if anyone like me was looking for a short simple answer. So, if I understood correctly, the client, who is making the request to a server is creating a Request object with a signal received() implemented (even with no parameters if the only thing he needs is a notification of something done), and the server has a slot which takes this request object by pointer, registers it in itself and on completion emits a signal. The receiver that gets the signal and no tokens are needed.